# Facebook SDK AppRequest behavior

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

So I'm using this code:

```
FB.AppRequest(
        "Catch diamond !",
        OGActionType.SEND,
        "1126946003993454",
        null,
        null,
        "Send a diamond !",
        FriendRequestCallBack);
```

And on device ( Android 5.0.2 ) it works fine, when I click on button dialog appears and I can choose friend from list, my friend recieves notification on Facebook app, but when he click on notification he receive an error "This topic is empty" with description "Page can not be displayed at this time. This could be a temporary problem, damaged or expired link or not authorized access." I don't know how to deal with this problem, and i don't know what my friend should see after click on notification, because I'm using AppRequest for the first time. Can someone explain this to me ? My app isn't published yet on Google Play Store, but is public on Facebook.

I was using [this](http://www.bigfootgaming.net/blog/tutorials/facebook-open-graph-objects-in-unity3d/) tutorial.

Thanks.

edit: Added link.

Comment: This tutorial means ? which ?

Comment: Have you researched to see if anyone had similar problems on SO?

Comment: Hyperlink added. Yes I have and I didn't find anything similar to my problem.

Comment: Someone can help me ? Please.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on Facebook SDK for Unity, but I did some apps using it.
After reading the Facebook documentation I got this:

public static void AppRequest(
    string message, 
    OGActionType actionType,
    string objectId,
    IEnumerable to,
    string data = "",
    string title = "",
    FacebookDelegate callback = null
)

Read the "Handling Requests In-game" from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/gamerequests). You forgot to handle the app request in the game.

Hope that helps.

Thanks.